# Simple SQL Statement in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a two tables (Brands and Customers) in my database.

Brands

[image: my tables]

Customers

What I want is firstly looking up BRANDID for each customer.
Then comapre if BRANDID matches agains BRANDID from BRANDS table.
If matched, appropriate BRANDNAME goes in Customers BRANDNAME.
If NOT matched, a string (Invalid) goes in Customers BRANDNAME.

Do I need to use INNER JOIN and CASE statement for this?

Comment: why you need to put BrandName column in Customer Table, You already referencing to BrandID. This will put data on multiple places which prone to data inconsistency and redundancy, As per design this is not required. If you need to display BrandName per Customer List, you cam use JOIN?

Comment: Can you add an example of your desired output? And please don't use screenshots for sample data. Use _formatted_ text (hint: click the `{}` button after selecting the text to be formatted)

Comment: What I am trying to do is actually checking a validation. I want to create a table joining current two tables. In the new table, there are more than BRANDID and BRANDNAME columns. Anyway when this is inserted I want to make sure if the BRANDID exists related BRANDNAME is also inserted otherwise, BRANDNAME is set to something else. The problem is when I try to join the table there is already a condition BRANDID from customer and BRANDID from brands are same. Which means the new table won't see any data that are not matched. but I also need to handle not matched or not joined values as well.

Comment: Again: please edit your question and add a sample of the output you want to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need an OUTER JOIN plus COALESCE:

```
select
   c.id,
   c.brandid,
   coalesce(b.brandname, 'Invalid')
from customers c
left join brands b on c.brandid = b.brandid;
```

This is pure Standard SQL and should run in any DBMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I think COALESCE as "If"? If existed then related values go but not existed then value in second parameter in COALESCE(a,b) go in the column?

Comment: Yep, `COALESCE` is actually a shortcut for `CASE WHEN b.brandname IS NOT NULL THEN b.brandname ELSE 'Invalid' END`, both are Standard SQL. Btw, Oracle's `NVL` is like `COALESCE`
 but proprietary

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has its own outer join syntax, which is much nicer than standard SQL, but here's the ANSI SQL enquiry:

```
select customers.id,customers.brandid,
 if(brands.brandname is null,'Invalid',brands.brandname) as 'Brandname'
 from customers
 left join brands on (customers.brandid = brands.brandid) ;
```

Comment: To access tabelsname.aCulumn, we need to join the tables don't we?

Comment: That's not ANSI SQL, because there is no `IF` in SQL. (Btw: Oracle discourages the use of their proprietary `(+)` operator for outer joins)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1537b5/1)

```
UPDATE Customers c
SET BRANDNAME = COALESCE( ( SELECT b.BRANDNAME
                            FROM   Brands b
                            WHERE  c.BRANDID = b.BRANDID ),
                          'Invalid' );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1537b5/1/0)**:

```
| ID | BRANDID | BRANDNAME |
|----|---------|-----------|
|  1 |       1 |     APPLE |
|  1 |       2 |       HTC |
|  1 |       3 |   SAMSUNG |
|  1 |      10 |   Invalid |
```